# $(window).height() issues in IE and FF

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, height

I wrote a script to make a dynamic sized `div` (#table) inside my page. I also have a menu (#menu) with a `nav` inside that establishes the min-height. In Chrome and Safari it all works ok, but in IE/FF not so much. In both I have the same problem: If I load the page full screen and then I minimize it with the minimize button, it takes the wrong  `$(window).height()`. If I reload it minimized, it works ok, I can even resize such that  the div adjusts ok. I put some images to be clear about what I'm talking about.

With FF I have another problem. It always has a space in the bottom of the div when the window size is bigger than the menu. Its like the value that I apply in the other browsers doesn't fit for Firefox. 
This problem is only with the height. The dynamic width works ok.

The **versions of my browsers** are the following: I think they are the latest ones.

- Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m
- Safari 5.1.7
- Internet Explorer 9
- Firefox 14.0.1

**Here is my javascript/jQuery code:**

```
<!-- Menu resize -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $('#menu').css({'height':(($(window).height())-350)+'px'});
    $('#table').css({'height':(($(window).height())-225)+'px'});
    $('#table').css({'min-height':(($('nav').height())-15)+'px'});
    $('#table').css({'width':(($(window).width())-135)+'px'});

    $(window).resize(function(){
          $('#menu').css({'height':(($(window).height())-350)+'px'});
          $('#table').css({'height':(($(window).height())-225)+'px'});
          $('#table').css({'width':(($(window).width())-151)+'px'});
    });
});
</script>
```

Part of page **style**:

```
/* NAV */

#line{
    width:1px;
    position:absolute;
    left:147px;
    top:123px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:#b3b3b3;
}

nav{
    width:147px;
    min-height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

nav li{
    display:block;
    width:147px;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    text-indent:30px;

    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:         inset 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
}

nav li a{
    color:#808080;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}

nav li:hover{
    background-color:#cccccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

nav li .active{
    background-color:#fdad06;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

nav li a.active{
    color:#7e5303;
}

nav li:first-child{
    border-top: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
}

nav #group{
    width:148px;
    height:49px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:49px;
    text-indent:22px;
}

/* SECTION */

#menu_and_content{
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
    box-shadow:inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2) 
}

#menu_and_content #menu{
    width:148px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-color:#b3b3b3;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

#menu_and_content #content{
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#table{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:500px;
}

#table table{
    width:100%;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    text-align:left;
    }

#table table thead th{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#969696;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#content table td, th{
    border-bottom:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#afafaf;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:0px 5px 0px 10px;
    line-height:24px;
}

#content table td:first-of-type, th:first-of-type {
    padding-left:4px;   
}

#content table tr:hover:not(#captions){
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    color:#3e3a34;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#content table input[type='checkbox']{
    margin-top:2px;
    border-color:#949494;
}

#login_container{display:block; height:260px;}
```

And **here are the images:**

[image: LAYOUT]

[image: CHROME]

[image: SAFARI]

[image: INTERNET EXPLORER (PROBLEM 1)]

[image: FIREFOX (PROBLEM 1)]

[image: FIREFOX (PROBLEM 2)]

Comment: Could you post the CSS for the #menu, #table, and nav elements?

Comment: Posted, sorry that i forgot that!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Firefox, and I solved it adding  to all my HTML files. The solution was pointed out in this stack overflow question:

[Why does Firefox return 0 as the value of $(window).height()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937494/why-does-firefox-return-0-as-the-value-of-window-height)

The **jQuery 1.8.1** release notes say

> Don’t use Quirks mode! jQuery has never supported Quirks mode and we
>   do not perform any testing in Quirks. This can affect values like
>   $("window").height(), and the jQuery 1.8 Quirks mode results did
>   change in order to support some modern browser features. The majority
>   of problem cases we’ve seen are from developers that wanted to be in
>   Standards mode but had an invalid doctype or extraneous markup before
>   their tag. When in doubt, use the simple and short .

Answer (score 1):

Try `innerHeight()` or `outerHeight()` instead of `height()`

The padding / borders / margins may not be included

Comment: I've just corrected the word `instead` it was `instad` and `Try` was `try`.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this blog. He made a very detailed research about screen measurements within the browser

http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/