# Internet explorer browser effective area

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

Given a complex JS application produced by GWT I need to use the complete browser area WITHOUT let scrollbar compare but not disabling them because there's a couple of exception to the rule, i need then to calculate the client area and since the tool selected it would be better directly in GWT but as it is supported also pure JS solution are acceptable.

as usual all browsers (chrome, safari, ff) except IE11 works fine with a standard solution of

```
 rootPanel.setPixelSize(Window.getClientWidth()-1,  Window.getClientHeight()-1);
```

but when it's used in IE11 on a screen 1440x900
the value of getClientHeight is 1440x845 (seems ok) but after rendering using this space scrollbars compare wasting space, exactly 10pixels..

```
 rootPanel.setPixelSize(Window.getClientWidth()-1,  Window.getClientHeight()-10);
```

seems to solve..where are gone this 10 pixel comparing the result with other browsers?
I think contents are not relevant since the size is set on body and first div

```
<html>
      <head>...
      <body style="width:1439;height:xxx;">
      <iframe out of visibility (position absolute and visible false
      <table style="width:1439;height;xxx">
```

and so on

Any guess where 10pixel can be lost?

Edit: I was forgetting an important detail: all happens when browser is maximised, if the browser is n't all seems working as expected!!!

Edit: looks like something close if not the same of

[$(window).height() issues in IE and FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325424/window-height-issues-in-ie-and-ff)

change just the origin of my JS code that comes from GWT but at the last stage should be the same, but still not solution

Answer (score 0):

Solved: when maximized the actual size is available late...the resize must take the size in a deferred moment, the module load usually implemented in GWT isn't the right time for this browser in the specific state..